# Can Android apps steal information from each other?

Tags: android, security

If I download an Android application, is it possible for one application to download the data of another application?

If an application asks permission for:

```
"Allow ABC to access photo, media, and files on your device"
```

Does giving permission mean it can now download all my personal photos?
Which files is it getting access too, my Gmail app's content i.e potentially all my emails?

Answer (score 3):

> is it possible for one application to download the data of another application?

That depends entirely on what "the data of another application" means:

- All apps that request permission can access [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), so if one app writes something to external storage, other apps can read it.
- Apps cannot read the content of another app's [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html), except on rooted devices.
- Apps can access anything published by another app via some API (e.g., a `ContentProvider`), subject to whatever security controls the app put on that API.

> If an application asks permission for: "Allow ABC to access photo, media, and files on your device" Does giving permission mean it can now download all my personal photos?

If those "personal photos" are on external storage, then yes.

> my Gmail app's content i.e potentially all my emails?

Not unless Gmail has a security flaw, or the app is using some API published by the Gmail app. In the latter case, usually some specific permission is required.

Comment: Is the android's photo application considered internal or external?  I think I can see it when I plug it into USB so that is external then?

Comment: @coolbreeze: Applications are not "internal" or "external". "Internal" and "external" refer to places to store files. I specifically linked to blog posts to provide more detail of what internal storage and external storage mean.

Comment: I mean to say, does photo's store in internal or external.  I was reading your post on external but couldn't understand where photo's stores my image data.

Comment: @coolbreeze: Well, since there is no single "android's photo application", I cannot really answer that. There are ~10,000 device models, which will ship with dozens or hundreds of "photo" applications pre-installed. Plus, users can install apps themselves. That being said, photos taken by typical camera apps are stored on external storage.